# Closing an application from within R

Tags: r

The command

```
browseURL("filepath/filename.extension")
```

opens the file: "filename.extension" using the application that is currently associated with it (in Windows).

*For example:*  browseURL("filepath/document1.docx") will open the file document1.docx using Microsoft Word (given that MS Word is the default program for this file).

**Question:**

But how do i close the file again, from within R?

Comment: I haven't seen this functionality in R yet, but I imagine if you had a C/Java/C++ program that does this, this would be trivial to run.

Comment: Something involving `system()` for sure? Maybe getting a list of processes and killing the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Maxim has said `system()` can help
i.e  Killing a notepad task

```
system("TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe")
```

Comment: Excellent! system("TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe")