# Playing multiple mp3 files from R

Tags: r, audio

I want to play multiple mp3 (sound) files one after the other. I have tried the following code and works fine except I have to manually close the windows media player (WMP) window after playing the first mp3 file so that the second mp3 file is played. Again I have to manually close WMP for the third mp3 file to be played. *Is there a way that I can automate the process without me having to manually close WMP windows now and then?* I am running the code in Windows 7 machine. Thanks!

```
library(tuneR)

File1<- readMP3("File1.mp3") # reading the mp3 files
File2<- readMP3("File2.mp3")
File3<- readMP3("File3.mp3")

play(File1) # playing the mp3 files
play(File2)
play(File3)
```

Comment: I think media player classic can play multiple files at once https://mpc-hc.org/downloads/. But most likely not a good SO question bc the programming isn't the issue but the Windows software.

Comment: Would converting the three files into a single song where they just play one after each and then playing that file work for you? If so you could use `bind` to essentially paste them together.

Comment: I want the audio to be played at different times in combination with some plots. Binding the three files into one wouldn't work in my case. Thanks!

Comment: You could take a look at the code for the play method `getMethod("play", "WaveGeneral")` but that will lead you to `getMethod("play", "character")` you'll see that basically it boils down to a call to `system`.  You could basically mimic that code but specify the "wait" parameter and set it to FALSE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing an application from within R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969342/closing-an-application-from-within-r)